# Cannot Resolve method 'setDisplayMode'(int, int, boolean)

Tags: java, libgdx

Can anyone suggest what should I change in the below code?

> Getting this After updating libgdx version 1.9.0.

**Cannot Resolve method** '`setDisplayMode'(int, int, boolean)`

```
            if (Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
                Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(currentWidth, currentHeight, false);
            break;
        case Keys.ENTER: // switch to fullscreen mode
            if (!Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
                Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().width,
                        Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().height, true);
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you update a library you should check the changelog, specially when it is a major update. see the changelog from [version 1.8.0](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/CHANGES#L259):

> - API Change: Graphics#setDisplayMode(DisplayMode) has been renamed to 
>     Graphics#setFullscreenMode(). If the window is in windowed mode, it will be switched 
>     to fullscreen mode on the monitor from which the DisplayMode stems from.
> - API Change: Graphics#setDisplayMode(int, int, boolean) has been renamed to 
>     Graphics#setWindowedMode(int, int). This will NOT allow you to switch to fullscreen anymore, 
>     use Graphics#setFullscreenMode() instead. If the window is in fullscreen mode, it will be
>     switched to windowed mode on the monitor the window was in fullscreen mode on.

So you have to use `setFullscreenMode()` or `setWindowedMode()`.

Comment: can you please suggest how replace, should i just replace them or need to make more changes withing code.

Comment: if (Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
                Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(currentWidth, currentHeight, false);
            break;
        case Keys.ENTER: // switch to fullscreen mode
            if (!Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
                Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().width,
                        Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().height, true);
            break;

Comment: @RohitVerma Which method you should use depends on what you want to do. When you want to go to fullscreen mode you use `setFullscreenMode()`, otherwise you use `setWindowedMode()`. However, you don't just replace the method name but you have also change the parameters since these methods have different arguments. Check the documentation/javadoc on how to use these methods and what the arguments should be like.

Comment: I tried this but app is crashing, after this code.

    if (Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
     Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode());
    break;
   case Keys.ENTER: // switch to fullscreen mode
    if (!Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
     Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode());

Comment: @RohitVerma When the application is crashing you have to check for error logs or exception messages to see what the problem is. Using `getDisplayMode()` for the argument of `setFullscreenMode` doesn't look right, but I don't know the library. You might need to use a display mode returned by the `getDisplayModes()` method (notice the `s` at the end, and the return type is an array for the available display modes).